# In android, the matrix operation very slow. How to improve this operation?

Tags: java, android, performance, opencv

I programmed android application using opencv.
At first, I started at visual c++ because I didn't know android function exactly.
There was no problem(speed) in visual c++. 
However, when I translated the c++ code to android code, the operation tasks was very slow. 
(I know desktop computer is more faster than android device.)

Therefore, I searched some information related to this problem and found that
java matrix accessing function(get, put) take a lot of time. (Bitmap also took many time)

How can I improve my application performance? 
(I want to know some efficient accessing way to images)
(Some people said that you should access using data type?, but I don't know the meaning and way.

In this below, there is a code which does subtraction operation in CIE Lab

```
    for (int i = 0; i < imageRows; i ++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < imageCols; j++ ) {
            imgColor1 = labImage[num].get(i, j);
            imgColor2 = labImage[num + 1].get(i, j);

            color1 = (int) Math.abs(imgColor1[0] - imgColor2[0]);
            color2 = (int) Math.abs(imgColor1[1] - imgColor2[1]);
            color3 = (int) Math.abs(imgColor1[2] - imgColor2[2]);

            if ((color2 + color3 > 5) || (color1 > 15)) {
                temp[0] = temp[1] = temp[2] = 255;
                img_temp.put(i, j, temp);
            } else {
                temp[0] = temp[1] = temp[2] = 0;
                img_temp.put(i, j, temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `labImage[num]` and `img_temp`?

Comment: Assuming it is a [`Mat`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html), you can make the `get` operations a lot faster by creating the `imageColorX` array once outside the loop, and pass it as a third parameter, i.e. `labImage[num].get(i, j, imgColor1);`. Otherwise, you are creating the array for each pixel.